# Custom Typeface EditText Focus

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, typeface

I'm using new features of lollipop such as **coloraccent, colorPrimary** in styles for pre-lollipop devices.

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_teal500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_teal600</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_white</item>
</style>
```

Now I want to create a custom typeface for my textview, edittext and button. **In styles i'm using coloraccent as white**. So on focus of edittext white color should come. See the below image for default edittext focus. This works fine.

[image: This is the picture of default edittext behavious]

But whenever i create a custom typeface edittext the focus behavior is different. **Its not showing the white color. Instead it showing in black color.** See the below image for my custom edittext behavior for Email.

[image: This is my custom edittext behaviour]

This is my custom edittext typeface class.

```
public class TypefaceButton extends Button {

    /*
     * Permissible values ​​for the "typeface" attribute.
     */
    private final static int ROBOTO_THIN = 0;
    private final static int ROBOTO_THIN_ITALIC = 1;
    private final static int ROBOTO_LIGHT = 2;
    private final static int ROBOTO_LIGHT_ITALIC = 3;
    private final static int ROBOTO_REGULAR = 4;
    private final static int ROBOTO_ITALIC = 5;
    private final static int ROBOTO_MEDIUM = 6;
    private final static int ROBOTO_MEDIUM_ITALIC = 7;
    private final static int ROBOTO_BOLD = 8;
    private final static int ROBOTO_BOLD_ITALIC = 9;
    private final static int ROBOTO_BLACK = 10;
    private final static int ROBOTO_BLACK_ITALIC = 11;
    private final static int ROBOTO_CONDENSED = 12;
    private final static int ROBOTO_CONDENSED_ITALIC = 13;
    private final static int ROBOTO_CONDENSED_BOLD = 14;
    private final static int ROBOTO_CONDENSED_BOLD_ITALIC = 15;
    /**
     * List of created typefaces for later reused.
     */
    private final static SparseArray<Typeface> mTypefaces = new SparseArray<Typeface>(16);

    /**
     * Simple constructor to use when creating a view from code.
     *
     * @param context The Context the view is running in, through which it can
     *                access the current theme, resources, etc.
     */
    public TypefaceButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML. This is called
     * when a view is being constructed from an XML file, supplying attributes
     * that were specified in the XML file. This version uses a default style of
     * 0, so the only attribute values applied are those in the Context's Theme
     * and the given AttributeSet.
     * <p/>
     * <p/>
     * The method onFinishInflate() will be called after all children have been
     * added.
     *
     * @param context The Context the view is running in, through which it can
     *                access the current theme, resources, etc.
     * @param attrs   The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
     * @see #TypefaceButton(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int)
     */
    public TypefaceButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        parseAttributes(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Perform inflation from XML and apply a class-specific base style. This
     * constructor of View allows subclasses to use their own base style when
     * they are inflating.
     *
     * @param context  The Context the view is running in, through which it can
     *                 access the current theme, resources, etc.
     * @param attrs    The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
     * @param defStyle The default style to apply to this view. If 0, no style
     *                 will be applied (beyond what is included in the theme). This may
     *                 either be an attribute resource, whose value will be retrieved
     *                 from the current theme, or an explicit style resource.
     * @see #TypefaceButton(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)
     */
    public TypefaceButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        parseAttributes(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Parse the attributes.
     *
     * @param context The Context the view is running in, through which it can access the current           theme, resources, etc.
     * @param attrs   The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
     */
    private void parseAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray values = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TypefaceTextView);

        int typefaceValue = values.getInt(R.styleable.TypefaceTextView_typeface, 0);
        values.recycle();

        setTypeface(obtaintTypeface(context, typefaceValue));
    }

    /**
     * Obtain typeface.
     *
     * @param context       The Context the view is running in, through which it can
     *                      access the current theme, resources, etc.
     * @param typefaceValue values ​​for the "typeface" attribute
     * @return Roboto {@link android.graphics.Typeface}
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if unknown `typeface` attribute value.
     */
    private Typeface obtaintTypeface(Context context, int typefaceValue) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Typeface typeface = mTypefaces.get(typefaceValue);
        if (typeface == null) {
            typeface = createTypeface(context, typefaceValue);
            mTypefaces.put(typefaceValue, typeface);
        }
        return typeface;
    }

    /**
     * Create typeface from assets.
     *
     * @param context       The Context the view is running in, through which it can
     *                      access the current theme, resources, etc.
     * @param typefaceValue values ​​for the "typeface" attribute
     * @return Roboto {@link android.graphics.Typeface}
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if unknown `typeface` attribute value.
     */
    private Typeface createTypeface(Context context, int typefaceValue) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Typeface typeface;
        switch (typefaceValue) {
            case ROBOTO_THIN:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_THIN_ITALIC:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_LIGHT:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_LIGHT_ITALIC:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_REGULAR:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_ITALIC:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_MEDIUM:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_MEDIUM_ITALIC:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_BOLD:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_BOLD_ITALIC:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_BLACK:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_BLACK_ITALIC:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_CONDENSED:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Condensed.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_CONDENSED_ITALIC:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-CondensedItalic.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_CONDENSED_BOLD:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf");
                break;
            case ROBOTO_CONDENSED_BOLD_ITALIC:
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-BoldCondensedItalic.ttf");
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown `typeface` attribute value " + typefaceValue);
        }
        return typeface;
    }

}
```

I used custom type face in xml like following.

```
<appname.utilities.TypefaceEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
        custom:typeface="roboto_light"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/user_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/material_grey200"
        android:textColorHint="@color/material_grey200" />
```

How i can resolve this! Any Idea? I know i can implement Custom Font in java class file. But I would like to implement in this way. In my own custom edit text also i want to show the same accent color. Thanks in prior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found it! For applying colorAccent just extend your custom EditText class from 
`android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`

Answer (score 1):

This is working for my custom `edittext`, lets try this code for your case. Add those 2 line of XML in your `Activity's` layout (layout of your `edittext`) :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
editText2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
  {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
     {
         editText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
         return false;
     }
  });
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: Sorry, i think i didn't convey my question properly. OnTouch of EditText it is focusing but the color is black for custom Typeface Edittext. But normal edit text color is White. I want custom typeface edittext also white in color.